# Laravel: Credit card field won't appear with Stripe integration

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, stripe-payments

I have copied and pasted the necessary Stripe code from the docs into my checkout.blade.php in my Laravel app:

```
@section('content')
<!-- Stripe elements -->
            <form action="/charge" method="post" id="payment-form">
                <div class="form-row">
                  <label for="card-element">
                    Credit or debit card
                  </label>
                  <div id="card-element">
                    <!-- A Stripe Element will be inserted here. -->

                  </div>

                  <!-- Used to display form errors. -->
                  <div id="card-errors" role="alert"></div>
                </div>

                <button>Submit Payment</button>
            </form>
            <!-- end Stripe elements -->
@endsection
```

```
@section('stripe')
    <script>
        (function(){
        // Create a Stripe client.
        var stripe = Stripe('blablabla');

        // Create an instance of Elements.
        var elements = stripe.elements();

        // Custom styling can be passed to options when creating an Element.
        // (Note that this demo uses a wider set of styles than the guide below.)
        var style = {
        base: {
            color: '#32325d',
            fontFamily: '"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif',
            fontSmoothing: 'antialiased',
            fontSize: '16px',
            '::placeholder': {
            color: '#aab7c4'
            }
        },
        invalid: {
            color: '#fa755a',
            iconColor: '#fa755a'
        }
        };

        // Create an instance of the card Element.
        var card = elements.create('card', {style: style});

        // Add an instance of the card Element into the `card-element` <div>.
        card.mount('#card-element');

        // Handle real-time validation errors from the card Element.
        card.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
        var displayError = document.getElementById('card-errors');
        if (event.error) {
            displayError.textContent = event.error.message;
        } else {
            displayError.textContent = '';
        }
        });

        // Handle form submission.
        var form = document.getElementById('payment-form');
        form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        stripe.createToken(card).then(function(result) {
            if (result.error) {
            // Inform the user if there was an error.
            var errorElement = document.getElementById('card-errors');
            errorElement.textContent = result.error.message;
            } else {
            // Send the token to your server.
            stripeTokenHandler(result.token);
            }
        });
        });

        // Submit the form with the token ID.
        function stripeTokenHandler(token) {
        // Insert the token ID into the form so it gets submitted to the server
        var form = document.getElementById('payment-form');
        var hiddenInput = document.createElement('input');
        hiddenInput.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
        hiddenInput.setAttribute('name', 'stripeToken');
        hiddenInput.setAttribute('value', token.id);
        form.appendChild(hiddenInput);

        // Submit the form
        form.submit();
        }
                })();
    </script>
@endsection
```

The label and the button renders on the screen but for some reason, the actual credit card input field will not display.

```
card.mount('#card-element');


<div id="card-element">
<!-- A Stripe Element will be inserted here. -->              
</div>
```

Shouldn't it automatically be mounted with the code above?

After reading the docs I thought the UI components were supposesd to be included in the code and for everything to display.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Include Stripe js in your html

```
<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I already have that. It's in my blade file.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and removing the `@section('scripts')` and the `endsection` resolved the issue